# Flutter file picker exception

Tags: android, flutter, filepicker.io

A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests' (type 'CompatibleScreensManifest').

or

unexpected element (queries) found in manifest
or

A problem was found with the configuration of task ':path_provider:generateDebugRFile' (type 'GenerateLibraryRFileTask').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android/build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
```

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

solution from:
https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Troubleshooting#-issue